# Json object with random key value

Tags: json, image, loops, object

I am developing an application, where I drag and drop images to grid, and after dropping I am creating a json object where I am adding that drop images to json object, there is a 144 square grid.

My json object gets created with entries:

```
27: Object
51: Object
54: Object
75: Object
99: Object
123: Object
125: Object
```

How can I loop through my exact key numbers in jquery for match with other json object?

Answer (score 0):

Sample Example:

```
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };

jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
  $( "#" + val ).text( "Mine is " + val + "." );

  // Will stop running after "three"
  return ( val !== "three" );
});

jQuery.each( obj, function( i, val ) {
  $( "#" + i ).append( document.createTextNode( " - " + val ) );
});
```

Output:

```
Mine is one. - 1
Mine is two. - 2
Mine is three. - 3
- 4
- 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over object's properties like this:

```
var obj = {1: 'val1', 2:'val2', 3:'val3' }
for (var param in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(param))
        console.log(obj[param])
}
```

And this will print:

```
val1
val2
val3
```